# Shop with two items

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models. `Shop` and `Item`. I am trying to retrieve all of the shops, with 2 items each - however, I cannot get it working. The value of `$shop['items']` is not changing.

```
foreach($shops as &$shop) {
    foreach($shop->items as $item) {
        $item->formatPreview();
    }

    $shop = $shop->toArray();

    $shop['items'] = array_slice($shop['items'], 2); 
}
```

How can I achieve this, and are there a smarter way using *Eloquent*?

Comment: What is the relation between `Shop` and `Item`? If `hasMany` then this is what you need: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

```
$shops = Shop::with('items')->get();

foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    echo 'shop name: '. $shop->name . '<br>';
        if($shop->items()->count()) {
            foreach ($shop->items()->take(2)->get() as $item) {
                echo 'item: ' . $item->name . '<br>';
            }
        }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

I was testing this inside a route closure so please format it as you want orfourse. Hope it is working now.

Comment: When doing it like this, I am only getting two items in total (not two per shop)

Comment: This would output the correct items, but the problem is the removal of the extra items

Comment: What do you mean with extra items?

Comment: If we assume a `Shop` have 10 items, I only want the first 2.

Comment: The code above does something like:
shop 1:
 - item 1
 - item 2
shop 2:
 - item xpto
 - item foo
etc

Comment: This causes `n+1` query issue.